# Как сменить активный элемент на следующий

Tags: javascript, jquery

Идея в том, что если мы не кликаем, то сразу заполняется первый элемент. Если у него `100% width`, то у этого элемента удаляем `class="active"` и `width="0"` и добавляем активный класс следующему и так до конца. Но есть возможность кликнуть на блок, тогда этот блок должен иметь `class="active"` и анимация `width` до `100%`, а у всех элементов сбрасывается, ну вроде как по клику работает, и начальный active тоже, но пока у меня начинаются проблемы когда нужно выбрать следующий элемент, как можно это сделать?

```js
$(function() {
  var st;
  $(".elem").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      return false;
    } else {
      var self = $(this);
      $(".elem").find(".load").css("width", "0");
      $(".elem").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");

      function timeCounter() {
        var totalTime = 0,
          sec = 0,
          loader = 0;

        clearInterval(st);
        st = setInterval(counter, 100);

        function counter() {
          if (sec > 99) {
            return false;
          } else {
            totalTime += 1;
            sec = parseInt(totalTime);
            loader = sec + "%";
          }
          $(self).find(".load").css("width", loader);
        };
      }
      timeCounter();
    }
  });

  $(".elem").each(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
      return false;
    } else {
      var self = $(this);
      $(".elem").find(".load").css("width", "0");
      $(".elem").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");

      function timeCounter() {
        var totalTime = 0,
          sec = 0,
          loader = 0;

        clearInterval(st);
        st = setInterval(counter, 100);

        function counter() {
          if (sec > 99) {
            $(self).next().addClass("active");
            $(self).removeClass("active");
            return false;
          } else {
            totalTime += 1;
            sec = parseInt(totalTime);
            loader = sec + "%";
          }
          $(self).find(".load").css("width", loader);
        };
      }
      timeCounter();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.elem {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.load {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  background: orange;
}

.elem.active {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elem active">
  <div class="load"></div>
</div>
<div class="elem">
  <div class="load"></div>
</div>
<div class="elem">
  <div class="load"></div>
</div>
<div class="elem">
  <div class="load"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я совсем ничего не понял из вашего вопроса. Вы переформулировать вопрос и кратко описать, чего вы хотите добиться?

Comment: да если честно сложновато немного)

Comment: с самого начала у нас загружаеться первый блок, когда полностью заполниться должен начаться загружаться следующий блок и так до конца

Comment: Я всё понял :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вам нужен этот эффект

```js
$(function() {
  var $_elem = $('.elem');
  
  // Создаём функцию анимации
  var f_setProgress = function ($_el) {
    // Удаляем у всех элементов класс и останавливаем все анимации
    $_elem.removeClass('active').find('.load').stop();
    // запускаем анимацию у нужного элемента
    $_el.addClass('active').find('.load').animate({width: 100 + '%'}, {
      duration: 5000, // 5 секунд
      easing: 'linear', // Линейный тип
      // По завершении загрузки, анимация включенится с ледующего элемента
      complete: function () {
        var $_nextEl = $_el.next(); // Выбираем следующий элемент
        
        // Проверяем, есть ли следующий элемент
        if ($_nextEl) {
          $_el.removeClass('active'); // Удаляем класс у этого элемента
          $_nextEl.addClass('active'); // Добавляем следующему
          f_setProgress ($_nextEl); // Запускаем анимацию у следующего элемента
        };
      }
    })
  };
  
  // Запускаем анимацию при нажатии
  $_elem.click(function () {
    f_setProgress ($(this));
  });
  
  // По началу запускаем анимацию у первого элемента
  f_setProgress ($_elem.eq(0));
});
```

```css
.elem {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.load {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  background: orange;
}

.elem.active {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="elem">
  <div class="load"></div>
</div>
<div class="elem">
  <div class="load"></div>
</div>
<div class="elem">
  <div class="load"></div>
</div>
<div class="elem">
  <div class="load"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Кураховские своих не бросают в беде, спасибо)

Comment: @DimaVleskov, Кураховские? Своих?

Comment: ты ведь с Курахово?

Comment: @DimaVleskov, да. Но почему "своих"? Ты тоже с Курахово что ли?

Comment: да тоже с Курахово) но щас переехал в Киев, работа и тд